# Div ao lado da outra com espaçamento bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Colegas.

Estou tentando criar esse layout:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o código abaixo, porém não estou conseguindo. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
<div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color: #F47B36; color: #FFF ">
<div style="padding: 10px">
<div class="col-xs-6"> teste </div>
<div class="col-xs-6"> <i class="fa fa-users fa-f5" aria-hidden="true"></i> </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color: #F47B36; color: #FFF; margin-left: 10px ">
<div style="padding: 10px">
<div class="col-xs-6"> teste </div>
<div class="col-xs-6"> <i class="fa fa-users fa-f5" aria-hidden="true"></i> </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color: #F47B36; color: #FFF; margin-left: 10px ">
<div style="padding: 10px">
<div class="col-xs-6"> teste </div>
<div class="col-xs-6"> <i class="fa fa-users fa-f5" aria-hidden="true"></i> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso você pode usar o offset:

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color: #F47B36; padding: 30px 10px;"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1" style="background-color: #F47B36; padding: 30px 10px;"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1" style="background-color: #F47B36; padding: 30px 10px;"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1" style="background-color: #F47B36;padding: 30px 10px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito Gabriel. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Por nada, mano!